# Docker service with upstart

Tags: docker, linuxmint

On linux mint 17 docker gives the following error when trying to start it via service docker start:

start: Unknown job: docker

I tried 2 versions already, the old 1.1 docker.io which is in the mint repository and the latest 1.5 from the docker website which can be installed through the get.docker.com script.

Any idea how to autostart this? Manual docker -dD works.

Thanks

Comment: What's the result of `service --status-all | grep docker` ?

Comment: shows up with [-] at the beginning, oh and this is upstart 1.12

Comment: Can you clarify the exact output ? Do you mean [-] show up in front of docker service ? This would mean the service is started and with the message you get it's likely that you haven't the rights to interact on it (missing sudo ?).

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26137834/starting-docker-as-daemon-on-ubuntu/34076885#34076885